# Writing custom widgets for lxqt

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt, widgets

I am using Lubuntu 22.04. I want to write a simple widget that would show a text in the right part of the panel ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfPdY.png)). This text would be taken from a RESTFul service. I already have a python code that extracts the proper text, just need a way to put it there. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: You mention (via tags) `lxpanel` which I can tell you won't help (that's a LXDE or GTK2 app & not the same as `lxqt-panel`).   I'd likely look at `nm-tray` or the network-manager [tray] tool written/maintained by the Lubuntu team if I wanted to create something like what you describe.... If that didn't provide what I wanted/needed; I'd likely explore `redshift-qt` next (ie. I'm picking things the Lubuntu team have created which is where I'd look for examples/ideas..)

Comment: Lxqt 1.1 contains the widget "custom command". You may install/compile this version of lxqt or switch to lubuntu kinetic(22.10) where lxqt is updated.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I think that should help.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański thanks for suggestion but I was looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: FYI:  LXQt 1.1 is being packaged/backported currently... @pasmanpasmański's solution also includes a 'wait' option too; if you watch in #lubuntu-devel on IRC you can see the packaging continue processing each day (*it's been in kinetic awhile; it's from there that it's been pushed|uploaded to debian/sid (which currently is well behind) & backports for jammy...*)